# Tcl/Tk Tkinter version 8.4 and 8.5 conflict on Mac Os X 10.4.11 with python 2.6.4

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am having trouble getting Tkinter up and runnning in order to install matplot lib.

I am running Mac OS X 10.4.11, and just installed Python 2.6.4 .

After several other fights, one remaining battle for me to get matlotlib installed is to have a working version of Tkinter, although there are several in my Mac from Xcode and also Python, I guess they just aren't installed in useful places? After I installed Python 2.6.4, import _tkinter failed. So I installed Tcl 8.5 from active state.

Now, I make it to the  Tkinter test:

> > > Tkinter._test()
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 3746, in _test
> > >           root = Tk()
> > >         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1645, in **init**
> > >           self._loadtk()
> > >         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1659, in _loadtk
> > >           % (_tkinter.TK_VERSION, tk_version)
> > >       RuntimeError: tk.h version (8.4) doesn't match libtk.a version (8.5)

I realize you have discussed the exact error I am describing here:
http://bugs.python.org/issue4017

but those errors arose from a problem  with an earlier version of python, where setup.py reversed the order of where to look. The advice in your previous post is to fix this order in setup.py and rebuild python, but my setup.py is already looking good - it includes these lines:

def detect_tkinter_darwin(self, inc_dirs, lib_dirs):
        # The _tkinter module, using frameworks. Since frameworks are quite
        # different the UNIX search logic is not sharable.
        from os.path import join, exists
        framework_dirs = [
            '/Library/Frameworks',
            '/System/Library/Frameworks/',
            join(os.getenv('HOME'), '/Library/Frameworks')

I would really appreciate any insight on how to handle this!( I am a biologist...)

While I'm at it, I'll include what is going on when I try to install m matplotlib in case it is useful...matplotlib thinks I have Tkinter 8.4 (ironically, only afeter I  installed 8.5, before that it always said it could not find Tkinter):

Tkinter: Tkinter: 65971, Tk: 8.4, Tcl: 8.4

also, here is the error I run into  when trying to build matplotlib:

powerpc-apple-darwin8-g++-4.0.1: unrecognized option '-syslibroot,/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk'
i686-apple-darwin8-g++-4.0.1: unrecognized option '-syslibroot,/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk'
/usr/bin/ld: -syslibroot: multiply specified
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
/usr/bin/ld: -syslibroot: multiply specified
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccrblCgU.out (No such file or directory)
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [mpl_build] Error 1

thank you!!

Katrine

Answer (score 2):

I think the important point from previous solutions proposed was that Python, upon install, detects the correct version and location of Tk. I assume you installed Tk after installing Python. This problem was solved on my machine when I reinstalled Python2.6 using the .dmg installer. I didn't need to rebuild or anything. I hope this helps. :)

Comment: This seems to have worked for me.  I installed the latest ActiveTcl 8.5.14 for Mac (as mentioned in the Python Tkinter docs) then did a clean install of Python 2.7.5 via ``brew`` with virtualenv, then ran a turtle package requiring Tkinter, and it all worked first time.  See http://www.lowindata.com/2013/installing-scientific-python-on-mac-os-x/ and do up to the parts involving virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper, then create a new virtualenv for your Tkinter project and install packages there.