# OSX Python Selecting ActiveStateTcl Framework instead of default System Tcl

Tags: python, macos, tcl

I'm trying to use the ActiveStateTcl Framework so I can specifically use TkTreeCtrl. After installation, python still did not recognize importing tktreectrl. It installed at
    `/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.6/`

When python prints the patchlevel of tcl, it displays 8.5.9, which is the framework located at 
    `/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/`

The Tk.framework is in the same path for both. How can I change what Framework its using? Copying the 8.6 Tcl/Tk frameworks over the 8.5 caused python to not recognize any tcl/tk modules.

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2247971/7552) suggests that re-installing python may detect the 8.6 installation of Tcl/Tk.

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried, it still uses the /System/Library instead.

Comment: Remove python and the Tcl.framework 8.5 version, then re-install python

Comment: Already tried that. I removed all Python and Tcl/Tk installations (except the default ones installed by Apple in /System/Library/Frameworks). Then I reinstalled Tcl/Tk 8.6 first, then installed python 3. Then I edited .profile to use /usr/local/bin/ before the others as suggested on ActiveState's website. Its still using the /System/Library/Framework version of 8.5.

Comment: "installed python" how? compile it from source, pointing where you have your new tcl installation, or use 'homebrew' - you can install tcl & python from there